# How do you make a button from second activity open a third activity?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to figure out the code to make a button from my second activity open a new third activity.

I just need to know the basic code for opening a third activity from a second activity button......

---

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class FifthActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fifth_layout);
    }
}
```

That is my activity.java file where the buttons are located....

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Amazon"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/amazon"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/amazon"
    android:layout_weight="0.07"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText"
    android:textSize="35sp" />
```

And that was my Fifth_Layout.xml

And.. I want to be able to open this image button from my second activity to my third activity. I just cant figure out the code to put into MainActivity.Java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to set a id of button in the layout. Then in onCreate() method you have to write:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fifth_layout);
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, ThirdActivity.class));
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Is there any video instruction on this? I keep getting errors.

Answer (score 0):

Do this

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        startActivity(new Intent(view.getContext(), ThirdActivity.class));
    }
});
```

Comment: When I put the code in, it says cannot resolve symbol 'button' and "Cannot resolve symbol 'view'. Suggestion?

Comment: You have to get a reference to your button like this: button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.my_button);

Answer (score 0):

**Fifth_Layout.xml**

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Amazon"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/amazon"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/amazon"
    android:layout_weight="0.07"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText"
    android:textSize="35sp" />
```

**activity.java**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fifth_layout);
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, ThirdActivity.class));
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: u forgot to add **android:id="@+id/button"** attribute in xml file.